# JavaFX8: How to create listener for selection of row in Tableview?

Tags: javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I currently have two tableviews in one screen, which results in both TableViews have rows which the user can select.

Now I want only one row to be selected at the same time (doesn't matter which TableView it is selected from). I was thinking about some kind of listener which deselects the other row when a row is selected. This is my initial setup:

**Step 1**
Search for a way to bind a method to the selection of a row (there is not something like `tableview.setOnRowSelected(method)`)

**Step 2**
Create the method which acts like a kind of listener: when a row is selected, deselect the other row (I know how to do this part)

```
Class1 selectedObject1 = (Class1)tableview1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
Class2 selectedObject2 = (Class2)tableview2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

if(selectedObject1 != null && selectedObject2 != null) {
   tableview1.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
}
```

So, step one is the problem. I was thinking of an observable list on which a listener can be created, and then add the selected row to the list. When this happens, the listener can call the method.
Anyone any clue how to make this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The `selectedItem` in the selection model is an observable property, so you should be able to achieve this with:

```
tableview1.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldSelection, newSelection) -> {
    if (newSelection != null) {
        tableview2.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
    }
});

tableview2.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldSelection, newSelection) -> {
    if (newSelection != null) {
        tableview1.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
    }
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! For others who want to use this: just put this code in the initialize part of your code. In my case, this is a controller of a FXML file.

Comment: What if SelectionMode is set to MULTIPLE? newSelection variable is just last selected item from table. How to get all selected?

Comment: @Wortig Add a `ListChangeListener` to `table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()`.

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be creating custom cell factory for table and set it for each table columns.

```
Callback<TableColumn<..., ...>, TableCell<..., ...>> value = param -> {
                TextFieldTableCell cell = new TextFieldTableCell<>();
                cell.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, event -> {
                            //your code
                        }
                );
                return cell;
            };
            packageName.setCellFactory(value);

    table1.column1.setCellFactory();
    table2.column1.setCellFactory();
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I see that your solution would work, but @James_D provided an answer which I prefer, because it is much simpler to implement.

Comment: it's just MOUSE_CLICKED event. It's not catching the keyboard events...

Answer (score 1):

I use it for deleting the chosen row.

```
public void ButtonClicked()
{
  ObservableList<Names> row , allRows;
  allRows = table.getItems();
  row = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();         
  row.forEach(allRows::remove);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This question helped me but during experiment in  javafx and jfoenix this also works for me.

```
deleteSingle.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (e) -> {

            StringProperty selectedItem = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getValue().link1;

            System.out.println("That is selected item : "+selectedItem);

            if (selectedItem.equals(null)) {

            System.out.println(" No item selected");


            } else {
                System.out.println("Index to be deleted:" + selectedItem.getValue());

                 //Here was my database data retrieving and selectd
                 // item deleted and then table refresh
                table.refresh();

                return;
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you need not only the row, but the **x|y position** of the table cell, do this:

```
table.getFocusModel().focusedCellProperty().addListener(
        new ChangeListener<TablePosition>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends TablePosition> observable,
            TablePosition oldPos, TablePosition pos) {
        int row = pos.getRow();
        int column = pos.getColumn();
        String selectedValue = "";

        if (table.getItems().size() > row
                && table.getItems().get(row).size() > column) {
            selectedValue = table.getItems().get(row).get(column);
        }

        label.setText(selectedValue);
    }
});
```

In this example, I am using a "classic" `TableView` with `List<String>` as column model. And, of course, that `label` is just an example from my code.

Comment: how would this help achieve OP's requirement (deselect the other table selection)? Obviously not at all ;)