# JavaFX populate data to tableView when user click on other tableView

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am currently working on a project, which is something like Inventory system. I am doing this using JavaFx, Scenebuilder.

> I have two TableViews, Date and Orders on the same FXML View and i already populate data to Date TableView, but I want to populate data on orders Tableview when user select the row of Date TableView.
>
> > The scenario is when user select row, Orders table populate and show the orders detail which take place on that date.

I know i have to implement listner and i tried from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424769/javafx8-how-to-create-listener-for-selection-of-row-in-tableview)

```
      @Override
                public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
                clientOrderDetail_tableCol_no.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<OrderDetail, Integer>("id"));
                clientOrderDetail_tableCol_items.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<OrderDetail, String>("items"));
                clientOrderDetail_tableCol_quantity.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<OrderDetail, Integer>("quantity"));
                clientOrderDetail_tableCol_totalPrice.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<OrderDetail, Double>("total"));
                clientOrderDetail_tableCol_pay.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<OrderDetail, Double>("pay"));
                clientOrderDetail_tableCol_due.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<OrderDetail, Double>("due"));
                clientOrderDetail_tableCol_paymentType.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<OrderDetail, String>("payType"));     


                clientOrderDetail_tableCol_dates.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<OrderDetail, String>("dates"));      

                //HERE I TRIED LISTNER
                clientOrderDetail_tableView_dates.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldSelection, newSelection) -> {

                refreshTable(newSelection.getDate());


    });
            }
```

> My tableRefresh method is

```
public void refreshTable(String date)
    {
        //String date = clientOrderDetail_tableView_dates.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getDate();
        Connection c = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try{

            c = DataBase.getConnection();
            stmt = c.createStatement();
            System.out.println(date);
            ResultSet rs = c.createStatement().executeQuery
                    ("SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE "
                            + "DATE = "+date+"");

            while (rs.next()) 
            {
                OrderDetail order = new OrderDetail();
                order.id.set(Integer.parseInt( rs.getString("ID")));
                order.payType.set(rs.getString("PAYTYPE"));
                order.pay.set(Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("PAY")));
                order.due.set(Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("DUE")));
                order.total.set(Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("TOTAL")));
                data.add(order);                
            }            
            clientOrderDetail_tableView.setItems(data);

            stmt.close();


            c.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

> My OderDetail Class

```
package structure;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class OrderDetail {


    public SimpleIntegerProperty id = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    public SimpleStringProperty items = new SimpleStringProperty();
    public SimpleIntegerProperty quantity = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    public SimpleDoubleProperty total = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    public SimpleDoubleProperty pay = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    public SimpleDoubleProperty due = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    public SimpleStringProperty payType = new SimpleStringProperty();
    public SimpleStringProperty date = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public void setID(Integer idSet)
    {
        id.set(idSet);
    }
    public Integer getId() {
        return id.get();
    }

    public void setName(String itemNameSet) {
        items.set(itemNameSet);
    }
    public String getName() {
        return items.get();
    }

    public void setQuantity(Integer quantitySet)
    {
        quantity.set(quantitySet);
    }
    public Integer getQuantity() {
        return quantity.get();
    }

    public void setTotal(Double totalPriceSet) {
        total.set(totalPriceSet);
    }
    public Double getTotal() {
        return total.get();
    }

    public void setPay(Double paySet) {
        pay.set(paySet);
    }
    public Double getPay() {
        return pay.get();
    }

    public void setDue(Double dueSet) {
        due.set(dueSet);
    }
    public Double getDue() {
        return due.get();
    }

    public void setPayType(String paymentTypeSet) {
        payType.set(paymentTypeSet);
    }
    public String getPayType() {
        return payType.get();
    }

    public void setDate(String dateSet) {
        date.set(dateSet);
    }
    public String getDate() {
        return date.get();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "OrderDetail [id=" + id + ", items=" + items + ", quantity=" + quantity + ", total=" + total + ", pay="
                + pay + ", due=" + due + ", payType=" + payType + ", dates=" + date + "]";
    }
}
```

> PROBLEM: The given code give no error but not populate data in Orders TableView when I am selecting row from date TableView.
>
> > Any helps would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How does that `OrderDetail` class look? Are there any rows in the result set/are there selectable rows in the `TableView` that just don't contain any content?

Comment: @fabian I added the class in Question.

Comment: I think the problem is with Listener.

Comment: It would be easy to print the `data` list before setting it, which would allow you  to check, if the `refreshTable` method is called and successfully runs the query and returns any items. BTW: Where you you create that list and why don't you clear it before filling new items. It seems to me that the list would contain the concatenation of the lists for items that have been selected...

Comment: I debug my code and after that i figured out that my sqllite query not working. so i remove where clause  from query and it works.

Comment: @fabian thank you very much, for printing the data advise, it really helps me to find the problem.