# JavaFX ChoiceBox does not display value through setValue()

Tags: java, javafx

I have a suspicion that I have stumbled upon a bug in JavaFX.

I have several `TableViews` that hold information about different objects.

[image]

In this example, I have an `Examiner` object with a name and a corresponding `Course` object.

I have created a function `selectExaminer()` that populates the Examiner name `TextField` and the Course `ChoiceBox` upon clicking on the `Examiner` object from the `TableView` with it's corresponding values.

But as can be seen from the screenshot above, only the `TextField examinerName` is populated, while the `ChoiceBox choiceBoxExaminer` is not. Here is the method: (it is called in the `initialize()` method)

```
  public void selectExaminer(){
examinerTableView.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
ObservableList selectedCells = examinerTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();

selectedCells.addListener(new ListChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onChanged(Change c) {
    if(selectedCells.size()>0)
    {
      Examiner aux = (Examiner) selectedCells.get(0);
      examinerName.setText(aux.getName());
      choiceBoxExaminer.setValue(aux.getCourse());          //here is the issue
      System.out.println("Choice box: " + choiceBoxExaminer.getValue());
      System.out.println("Actual object: " + aux.getCourse());
      lastExaminerSelectedName = examinerName.getText();
    }
  }
});
```

The `ChoiceBox` dropdown does work but doesn't display the value set through .setValue()

[image]

When printing to the console the value of the `Course` of the actual Examiner and the one from the `TableView`, both show that they are populated.

```
      System.out.println("Choice box: " + choiceBoxExaminer.getValue());
      System.out.println("Actual object: " + aux.getCourse());
```

[image]

But alas... the `ChoiceBox` is still blank.

This issue arose after implementing data storage to binary files (this is a college project, no db), although I'm not sure how it influences the particular issue

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424769/javafx8-how-to-create-listener-for-selection-of-row-in-tableview

Comment: [mcve] please .. at least in your next question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `choiceBoxExaminer.getSelectionModel().setSelectedItem(aux.getCourse());`

But, honestly, you make a good point; you would think that `setValue()` would also do the trick.

Comment: `choiceBoxExaminer.getSelectionModel().setSelectedItem(aux.getCourse());` per se did not work, however instead of `aux.getCourse()` i have used an index `i` representing the position in the Array, and it does work!

Answer (score 0):

```
aux.getCourse()
```

Make sure that the return value is exactly the same as an item in the list added to the choiceBox. Only choicebox.setValue() works:

```
String[] fruits = {"apple", "orange"};
choiceBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(fruits);
choiceBox.setValue("grape");//this won't work since grape isn's in the list. 
choiceBox.setValue("orange"); // choicebox will display the value.
```